# Error in VS22 Can't find "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading, Version=17.3.0.0"

Tags: c#

I am trying to make an extension that works in VS19 work in VS22. It says it can't find the file or assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading, Version=17.3.0.0. In my project references it shows Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading and in Manage NuGet Packages is shows Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading 17.3.44. Not sure why it can't find Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading at runtime.
I would have put in screen shots but haven't earned enough credits to do that. I will bite my tongue.
I am new in this environment after 42 years of IBM mainframe assembler language. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I avoid an error loading Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58719511/how-can-i-avoid-an-error-loading-microsoft-visualstudio-threading-in-visual-stud)

Comment: I read that post before I asked the question. Didn't seem to apply to my situation. Thanks anyway.

Comment: C1sc0 I apologize, I did get the answer eventually from that post. I was reading and all the answers seemed to be pre VS22. Down below was a post about VS22 specifically. From that post we figured out that I needed to update VS22. I no longer get this error. Thank you!